# Why application of Sharkovskii's Theorem to Collatz is wrong?

Tags: functions, dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems, collatz-conjecture

I thought about this years ago but never had it resolved. [Sharkovskii's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharkovskii's_theorem) has a corollary according to Wikipedia that if there exists a 3-cycle on a map on $\mathbb{R}$, then the map has $n$-cycles for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Now, the Collatz map $f(x)$ has a 3-cycle: $f(f(f(4))) = 4$...

Now, I assume the conclusion that the Collatz map has cycles of every size is wrong (otherwise, it would have been solved) but why does it not apply here?

Comment: To what function on $\mathbb R$ would you apply Sharkovskii?  How do you plan on ensuring that the other cycles are subsets of $\mathbb N$?

Comment: This is a good point... I guess $\frac{1}{4}(1+4x-(1+2x)cos(\pi x))$ but then it doesn't say anything about Collatz (which is about $\mathbb{N}$)...

Comment: The hypothesis of Sharkovskii's Theorem assumes $f$ is a comtinuous function from $I$ to $I$, where $I$ is a subinterval of $\mathbb{R}$..

Comment: Actually, @quasi, the corollary I mention works on continuous functions $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: But it doesn't guarantee that any subset of the domain which has a periodic point of order $3$ has periodic points of all orders.

Comment: You claim that the consequence works for noncompact intervals? Don't see how to prove it...

Comment: You can have cycles of **any length** over the rational-numbers $\mathbb Q$. Integer-numbers $\mathbb Z$ might simply be too special...

Answer (score -1):

In short, the Collatz conjecture does have cycles of every period, including $3$, but this is over the 2-adic numbers.  It is, by and large, topologically conjugate to the [Dyadic Transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_transformation).

Two functions are topologically conjugate to each other when there is a homeomorphism which conjugates one to the other.  A consequence of topological conjugacy is that functions which are topologically conjugate share the same orbits.

A little more precisely - the Dyadic map has transitive orbits of period $n$ which are in one to one bijection with the base $2$ [Lyndon words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyndon_word) of length $n$.  If one converts the Dyadic Transformation to the Cantor set by writing every binary number in the unit interval with twos in place of ones, and reinterpret it as a base $3$ number, the Dyadic map remains pretty much the same except it now has one additional orbit terminating in a fixed point.  This function is now **exactly** topologically conjugate to the **Bit Shift map** on 2-adic numbers, which is given by $x\mapsto (x-1)/2$ for odd $x$ and $x\mapsto x/2$ for even $x$.

The bit shift map is topologically conjugate to any other shift map on the 2-adic numbers where you replace the $(x-1)$ part with $ax-b$, where $a,b$ are two 2-adic units (i.e. odd numbers).  They all have orbits of the full gamut of periods, enumerated by the length $n$ base $2$ Lyndon words.

The challenge is to show that the unique period $2$ orbit is the only one which the natural numbers fall into.

**EDIT**

Sorry this is an edit following the downvote, in case this much wasn't clear from the above... the function $x\mapsto x+2^{\nu_2(x)}$ shares precisely the same transitive orbits as the bit shift map, and is continuous on the 2-adic numbers. Then by the topological conjugacy given above you get a homeomorphism to the Cantor set, then using the devil's staircase you have a homeomomorphism from the Collatz conjecture to a continuous endomorphism on a segment of $\Bbb R$, hence the system having periodic points of period $3$ and every period by Sharkovskii's theorem.